# Java application database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a table from a database called Author. The AuthorId is of the type author increment and the name I insert in the Gui( NetBeans ). Afterall I am able to display all the names in a JComboBox. How can I display its respective id in a textfield everytime I click on an author from the comboBox?
[Below is the code that i used in order to display the names coming from the database into the comboBox. how do i do to click in oone of the items and get its respective iD from the database?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8lge.png)

Comment: I used the following code to get all the names from the database and put in a comboBox. What I am now struggling is to be able to get the respective AuthorId everytime I click from the comboBox:

            conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
            pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from Author");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();            
            while(rs.next())
            {
                authorId = rs.getInt("AuthorId");
                String authorName = rs.getString("AuthorName");
                authorComboBox.addItem(authorName);   
            }

Comment: Please edit your post with this information. It is 1) not a comment and 2) unreadable in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `Object` that holds both the `id` and the `name` and pass this to the `authorComboBox.addItem(new IdItem(1,"Test"));`

Example of IdItem class

```
public class IdItem {
    private int id;
    private String description;

    public IdItem(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (description == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return description;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof IdItem) {
            return ((IdItem) obj).getId() == this.getId();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IdItem clone() {
        return new IdItem(id, description);
    }
}
```

Note I have `override` the `toString()` since the `Combox` calls this to render the item.

When you call `getSelectedItem()` the `combobox` will return the selected IdItem, hence you can get the id.